# How to enable custom stage library for streamsets data collector?

Tags: streamsets

I have custom stage library which I want to use in Streamsets Data collector pipeline, I have followed all the steps given in below link to install custom stage lib, but still I am not able search stage library data collector.

Could you please help ?

SS document link  :
docs.streamsets.com/datacollector/latest/help/datacollector/UserGuide/Configuration/CustomStageLibraries.html#concept_pmc_jk1_1x

Comment: Is this a new sdc installation?  If you followed the instructions in the documentation, what was the result?  What failed when SDC restarted; did you get an error message in the sdc.log?   The additional information could help to diagnose the issue.

Comment: This is not fresh installation, actually I have upgraded version of Streamset to 3.22, after that I am not able to load custom library. I can not see any error message in the sdc.log and able start the streamsets, but after installation if I try to search the custom lib on canvas then it is not showing

Answer (score 0):

There are only a few things to check:

First, ensure you've exported the USER_LIBRARIES_DIR environment variable so SDC can find the custom stage libraries:

```
export USER_LIBRARIES_DIR="/opt/sdc-user-libs/"
```

Then give the custom stage library the appropriate permissions in the JVM's security manager. (Verify that you've added a section like this example to the $SDC_CONF/sdc-security.policy file):

```
// custom stage library directory
grant codebase "file:///opt/sdc-user-libs/-" {
   permission java.security.AllPermission;
};
```

Verify that you've restarted SDC to pick up the previously-mentioned changes.

After restarting SDC, ensure the custom stage's jar files have been opened by the JVM:

```
lsof -p (sdc pid) | grep (jar file name)
```

The documentation can be found [here](https://docs.streamsets.com/portal/datacollector/3.22.x/help/datacollector/UserGuide/Configuration/CustomStageLibraries.html?hl=custom)